# Unique names on the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

Take for example two apps on the iOS App Store: "Witness" and "Witness Remote". However, if you download them both, you will notice that they are actually both named only "Witness" on the iPhone.

So, when Apple says that app names must be unique, are they only talking about the app name as it appears on the store, and not its **actual name** when installed on the device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name that appears under the app's icon when it is installed on your iOS device is actually the "Bundle Display Name" (specified in the app's plist).  This can be different than the App's name in he App Store - frequently developers use a shortened version of the App Name if the App Name is too long to fit in the space under the icon.  The App's name needs to be unique, as you note, however the Bundle Display Name, which is what the user sees once the app is installed, does not need to be so.

Comment: Thanks! Does this also hold true on the Mac App Store and Mac apps?